# How to redirect user inside vue-resource http interceptor?

Tags: vuejs2, vue-router, vue-resource

I want to redirect the user when I have an 401, but I can't access the `router` from this context:

```
  Vue.http.interceptors.push(function(request, next) {
    // continue to next interceptor
    next(function(response) {
        if(response.status == 401){
            //redirect user here
            //tried: Vue.$router and Vue.$route 
        }

    });
  });
```

How can I make this?

*Using: Vue-router and Vue-resource*

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
const router = new VueRouter({
  routes
})

Vue.http.interceptors.push(function(request, next) {
    // continue to next interceptor
    next(function(response) {
        if(response.status == 401){
            router.push(...) 
        }
    });
 });
```

Comment: This works! But if I have this two in separated files, I will need to pass router as a param, right? I just don't understand will I can't make `Vue.$router` or something like that.. but thanks for your answer!

Comment: @thur Yes, if they are in different files you will need to import or expose it like `window.router` or something to that effect.